# ng-model does not pass values to the scope of my login page -returns 'undefined'

Tags: angularjs

My head is almost cracking. I am trying to make a login page and I have managed to solve the Angular `$http.post()` issue well.

Now the values typed in input fields are not passed to the scope. When I try to access them like `$scope.loginuser` it returns undefined:

`login.html`

```
<form   name="loginForm"   novalidate>


            <h2 align="center" style="color: #fff;">Please Sign In</h2>
            <hr class="colorgraph">
                <div ng-hide="logResponse" class='alert alert-danger'>Wrong username or password.</div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" name="username"  class="form-control" ng-model="loginuser" placeholder="Username/Email Address" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="password"  class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">

                    <button ng-show="actionbtn" type="submit" ng-disabled="loginForm.username.$error.required || loginForm.password.$error.required" class="btn btn-success btn-block" ng-click="doLogin()">Sign In</button> 
                <h4 class="white" align="center" ng-hide="actionbtn">Logging You In...</h4>
                <h4 class="white"  align="center" >{{label}}</h4>
            </div>
            <hr class="colorgraph">

    </form>
```

controller:

```
// Perform the login action when the user submits the login form
$scope.doLogin = function() {

$scope.actionbtn = 0;


$http({
url: 'http://localhost/socialkit/v1.2.2/script/app-request.php',
method: "POST",
data: {'login_id': 'Check'+ $scope.loginuser}
}).then(function(response) {
    // success
  if(response.data.status == 200){

        var done = window.open('http://localhost/socialkit/v1.2.2/script', '_self', 'location=yes');

    }else{
        $scope.logResponse = 0;
        $scope.actionbtn = 1;
        $scope.label=response;
    }
}, 
function(response) { // optional
    // failed

    $scope.logResponse = 0;
        $scope.actionbtn = 1;
}
);
```

Comment: you model assigned to username field is loginuser so instead  of $scope.username use $scope.loginuser

Comment: @Safi that is just an example. The code reflects the same variable name.

Comment: Where do you see that they're undefined ?

Comment: @OmriAharon I am returning the respose back to the page with `{{label}}` it shows `{"login_id": checkundefined}` meaning that the string past ``check` is returned but the `$scope` part is not. When I use the `$scope` variable alone without the string part, things break down

Comment: The $scope.label is showing the response.  To check where "ng-model does not pass values to the scope",  add {{loginuser}} just behind the {{label}}. Your question is not about some opinion on approach where it could described with some pseudo code. Instead it is about s concrete problem, where you must avoid typos.

Comment: @UlukBiy That is true, I am sure it is a tiny typo killing me here. I am redoing the whole thing and it seems to be going well.